# GC Behavior and CLR Thread Hijacking

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, clr

I was reading about the GC in the book `CLR via C#`, specifically about when the CLR wants to start a collection.  I understand that it has to suspend the threads before a collection occurs, but it mentions that it has to do this when the thread instruction pointer reaches a safe point.  In the cases where it's not in a safe point, it tries to get to one quickly, and it does so by `hijacking` the thread (inserting a special function pointer in the thread stack).  That's all fine and dandy, but I thought managed threads by default were safe?

I had initially thought it might have been referring to unmanaged threads, but the CLR lets unmanaged threads continue executing because any object being used should have been pinned anyway.

<strike>So, what is a `safe point` in a managed thread, and how can the GC determine what that is?</strike>

EDIT:

I don't think I was being specific enough.  According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678ysw69.aspx), even when `Thread.Suspend` is called, the thread will not actually be suspended until a `safe point` is reached.  It goes on to further state that a `safe point` is a point in a threads execution at which a garbage collection can be performed.

I think I was unclear in my question.  I realize that a Thread can only be suspended at a safe point and they have to be suspended for a GC, but I can't seem to find a clear answer as to what a safe point is.  What determines a point in code as being safe?

Comment: Safe by the CLR, not from the CLR.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

'Safe Points' are where we are:

1. Not in a catch block.
2. Not inside a finally
3. Not inside a lock
4. <strike>Not inside p/invoke'd call (in managed code).</strike> Not running unmanaged code in the CLR.
5. The memory tree is walkable.

Point #5 is a bit confusing, but there are times when the memory tree will not be walkable.  For example, after optimization, the CLR may new an Object and not assign it directly to a variable.  According to the GC, this object would be a dead object ready to be collected.  The compiler will instruct the GC when this happens to not run GC yet.

Here's a blog post on MSDN with a little bit more information: https://web.archive.org/web/20160215234236/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/09/02/netcf-gc-and-thread-blocking.aspx

EDIT: Well, sir, I was WRONG about #4.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2000/december/garbage-collection-part-2-automatic-memory-management-in-the-microsoft-net-framework) in the 'Safe Point' section.  If we are inside a p/invoke (unmanaged) code section then it is allowed to run until it comes back out to managed code again.

However, according to [this MSDN article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150704013841/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevenpr/archive/2004/07/26/197254.aspx), if we are in an unmanaged portion of CLR code, then it is not considered safe and they will wait until the code returns to managed.  (I was close, at least).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense, particularly #5, the entire memory structure needs to be in a verifiable state for the GC to run a collection.  It's a very simple concept when you have the answer, it was just getting there that I was having trouble with.  Thanks!

Comment: This is about the most detailed answer I can find at this time online about what a gc safe point is. Thanks Dan! That said, I still would like to add: why 1/2/3 are not considered safe points?

Answer (score 0):

Actually none of the answers I found so far on SO explains the 'why', i.e. what makes a certain point in code unsafe. And for that, from what've read in "Pro .NET Memory Management", the answer seems to be: in principle every point in code *can* be safe point as long as there're GCInfo generated by JIT to fully describe GC roots for that given point in code.

However, it's both impractical (think about the memory overhead, we're talking about GCInfo for every CPU instruction) and unnecessary (because what matters really is the "time-to-safe-point" (TTSP), it's sufficient to generate safe points with a granularity that makes this TTSP latency sufficiently small) to generate safe point for every struction.

Therefore, the JIT compiler uses some heuristics to decide how often safe points are generated so that it can tradeoff between memory overhead (not too often), and gc latency due to TTSP delay (not too few). Most of the time it's sufficient to just rely on method call site to act as safe points as they happen frequently enough to make TTSP delay very small. One of the exceptions is tight loop within which no method calls are made, in which case JIT may decide to inject safe points at loop repetition boundary.

So to sum it up, nothing fundamentally makes a particular point in code "unsafe" for GC. It's only a matter of tradeoff by JIT to decide how often safe-points are inserted.